# Resolve dependencies by context - deep down the resolve tree

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container

We have two applications that share some common classes with dependencies.
These dependencies are then same for both, or application specific.

Now configuring IoC for both apps is easy - use ImplementationA as IDependency for one app and ImplementationB as IDependency for another.

BUT - there is third app that sometimes, when resolving interface needs to use dependecies of app A and sometimes of B. In other words I need something like this:

```
Resolve<ISomething>( when you come accross IDependecy (anywhere in the 'resolve tree') use ImplementationA)

Resolve<ISomething>( when you come accross IDependecy (anywhere in the 'resolve tree') use ImplementationB)
```

*So the core problem is*: how do you pass context to whatever logic, that chooses the implementation, from Resolve call?

Concrete example:
.NET Core MVC App - enum value is parsed from request. Now I need to call some IManagerFactory, pass this enum as argument and get the implementation of the manager with all the dependecies from application A or B. (again, deep down not just dependencies of the manager itself)
Getting the context from request is time consuming so I only want to do it once. And this is already done at the beginning of the method. Like this

```
public async Task<Response> ProcessRequest([FromBody] Request request)
{
 var context = _someService.GetContext(request);
 var appType = ParseAppTypeFromContext(context);
 ...
 var manager=  _managerFactory.Resolve(appType);
 manager.DoSomething();
 manager.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

**Possible solutions:**

1. I could register ISomethingA, use registration delegate and have it resolve the correct dependencies by ResolvedParameter (Autofac feature) - and then just resolve ISomethingA.

But I would have to do it for every single class that depends on the IDependecy and every class that depends on that class and so on - work my way up.

2. Use factories.
   But you still have to tell it somehow which implementation you want. So I would have to pass that information from top to bottom - that seems a little.. wrong, since these are common classes that shouldn't know there is some app A or B.

So.. I'm lost. I'am not sure if this is case for IoC or better design. Please advise.
 (I don't really care which IoC container I use - as long as it's good and maintained)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Factory would, IMO, indeed be the wrong approach. A Factory complicate the consumer of `IDependency` and the introduction of this Factory abstraction can cause sweeping changes throughout the application.

Instead, I think the most appropriate solution is to apply the Proxy pattern. This Proxy will be an implementation of `IDependency` and it will wrap both `IDependency` implementations, and will dispatch any incoming call to the correct implementation, based on the conditions that you specify.

For instance:

```cs
public class DependencyDispatcher : IDependency
{
    private ImplA a;
    private ImplB b;

    public DependencyDispatcher(ImplA a, ImplB b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    private IDependency Dependency => someCondition ? this.a : this.b;

    // Implement IDependency methods to forward the call to Dependency
    void IDependency.DoSomething() => this.Dependency.DoSomething();
}
```

You can configure this Proxy to be the default implementation of `IDependency` in the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) of your third application.

Your update makes things more clear. You are posing some runtime value with the request, and you need to make a decision based on this value.

There are a few solutions here. First of all, try moving this decision *out of the  request's body* and into the *request header*. This way, your dispatcher can do the following:

```
private IDependency Dependency => 
    HttpContext.Current.Headers["MyHeader"] == "something" ? this.a : this.b;
```

If that's not an option, and the information *belongs* in the request body, you might be able let your dispatcher make the decision based on its input. For instance:

```
public class DependencyDispatcher : IDependency
{
    ...

    private IDependency GetDependency(string appType) =>
        appType == "a" ? this.a : this.b;

    void IDependency.DoSomething(DoSomethingData data) =>
        this.GetDependency(data.AppType).DoSomething(data);
}
```

This is obviously only possible if that `AppType` value (or a value that can be converted to it) is supplied to the `IDependency`'s method(s). Only in that case, there is enough information available do make this decision.

If that's not an option, another option is to define an abstraction that allows setting the runtime value in the object graph, which feeds the dispatcher with the information for that request. For instance:

```
public interface IApplicationContext
{
    AppType ApplicationType { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller can get this `IApplicationContext` injected and set the `AppType` property:

```
public async Task<Response> ProcessRequest([FromBody] Request request)
{
    var context = _someService.GetContext(request);
    this.applicationContext.ApplicationType = ParseAppTypeFromContext(context);
    this.dependency.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Alternatively, you might be able to add some piece of middleware that sets the `AppType` before the controller's Action method is invoked.

You can let the Proxy implement `IApplicationContext` as well:

```cs
public class DependencyDispatcher : IDependency, IApplicationContext
{
    ...
    public AppType ApplicationType { get; set; }

    private IDependency Dependency => ApplicationType == AppType.A ? this.a : this.b;

    // Implement IDependency methods to forward the call to Dependency
    void IDependency.DoSomething() => this.Dependency.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: But how do you pass the information about which implementation to use, from resolve call to DependencyDispatcher? Or more accurately - from factory that will call resolve. That's the main problem - that the logic to choose the implementation is context dependent. It's not something that can be set globally.

Comment: Well, that's a question I can't answer for you, since you haven't described on what information and conditions you need to make the switch. Can you update your question and show some concrete examples of what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Something along the lines of IApplicationContext came to my mind but there is one catch - this works only if you have one appType per scope (or as long as it synchronous - otherwise it may happen that one instance changes the appType of another). 
Which is actually this case, but I was hoping for more universal solution since we may need to use it in another app in the future. (and it may very well beasynchronous)
But this is still very good and I guess we'll have to deal with the asynchronous when and if it comes. 
So thanks :)